# Backbone Javascript - Function not Found?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I keep getting a "filterMessages is not a function" error.  Here's the Backbone View class - no idea why it can't find the function.

Here's the error in Firebug
filterMessages is not defined
Line 152 (filterMessages("all").each(function(message) {

```
MessageListView = Backbone.View.extend({

    defaults : {
        filterString : "all"
    },

    initialize : function() {

        this.collection.on("add", function(model) {
            var view = new MessageView({model: model});
            $("div.cameras").prepend(view.render().el);
        });

        this.collection.on("remove", function(model) {
            var ID = model.id;
            $("#message-" + ID).parent("div.message").remove();
        });

        this.collection.on("reset", function(models) {
            $("div.cameras").empty();
            filterMessages("all").each(function(message) {
                var view = new MessageView({model: message});
                $("div.cameras").prepend(view.render().el);
            });

        });

    },

    setFilter : function(filterString) {
        this.filterString = filterString;
        this.collection.reset(this.collection);
    },

    filterMessages : function(filterString) {
        return this.collection.filter(function(model){

            if (filterString == "all")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (filterString == "active")
            {
                return model.get("ignore") == "0";
            }
            else if (filterString == "ignore")
            {
                return model.get("ignore") == "1";
            }
            else if (filterString == "flag")
            {
                return model.get("flag") == true;
            }

        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will want to call it within the context of the view:

```
initialize : function() {

    var self = this;

    // code here

    this.collection.on("reset", function(models) {
        $("div.cameras").empty();
        self.filterMessages("all").each(function(message) {
            var view = new MessageView({model: message});
            $("div.cameras").prepend(view.render().el);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, that did it.  Thanks.  An annoying 'feature' of JS.

Answer (score 0):

Just define "this" as a variable outside your inner function, because it will take a different property when inside your inner function.

```
primaryFunction : function() {
    var self = this;

    innerFunction : function(filterString) {
        self.someOtherFunction();
    };
}
```